# Inserting node into BST changes previous nodes

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I am new to the concept of BST and in order to do an assignment, I have to make a crossword game with the concept. Everything else works fine except when trying to insert new Words into the BST.
For example if:
Word 1: SWORD
Word 2: TWIRL

Both nodes 1 and 2 will hold TWIRL in their word value.

The input section in the snippet below is simplified, but maybe it's useful to know that the `root = insertWord(root, count, column, row, oriId, word);` is stored at the end of a do-while loop, though that shouldn't affect things.

Struct Declaration

```
struct Words {
    int id;
    int col;
    int row;
    int ori; // 0 Horizontal, 1 Vertical
    char *word;
    Words *left, *right;
} *root = NULL;
```

BST Insert

```
Words *newWord(int id, int col, int row, int ori, char *word) {
    Words *newWord = (Words*)malloc(sizeof(Words));
    newWord->id = id;
    newWord->col = col;
    newWord->row = row;
    newWord->ori = ori;
    newWord->word = word;
    newWord->left = NULL;
    newWord->right = NULL;
    
    return newWord;
}

Words *insertWord(Words *node, int id, int col, int row, int ori, char *word) {
    if(node == NULL) {
        node = newWord(id, col, row, ori, word);
    }
    else if(id > node->id) {
        node->right = insertWord(node->right, id, col, row, ori, word);
    }
    else if(id < node->id) {
        node->left = insertWord(node->left, id, col, row, ori, word);
    }
    else {
        printf("Can't insert the same value");
    }
    
    return node;
}
```

Input

```
char word[25];
print("Word [1 to go back] : "); scanf(" %s", &word);
root = insertWord(root, count, column, row, oriId, word);
// count is the number of words, oriId is orientation
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: You aren't making a copy of the data, but save a pointer to a buffer where it was given. So the next data entry will change all previous entries, as they all point to the same buffer. Consider using `newWord->word = strdup(word);`. Aside: `scanf(" %s", &word);` should be `scanf("%24s", word);`

Comment: E.g. `newWord->word = word;` think about what that does. In fact, *run your program in a debugger* and put a breakpoint on that line, then step it and see what is actually transpiring each time it executes, paying close attention to the value of the address being stored, not the string content within.

Comment: I think I understand now, I made another program with BST yesterday (a simpler one) and node->char* = char* worked fine there, so I assumed that's the way to do it. Reading into strdup though I get why that's the proper way of doing it. Thank you for the information guys, I still have a lot to learn about C and BST.

Comment: `Words *left, *right;` <<-- it appears you are using a C++ compiler

Comment: Yes I am using the cpp file type

Comment: Side note `"%24s"`: It's pretty unfortunate that `scanf` does *not* allow for an asterisk variant to specify the size as argument (`scanf("%???s", sizeof(array) - 1, array)`. One *can* work around, though: `#define FORMAT_SIZE 24 #define ARRAY_SIZE (FORMAT_SIZE + 1) scanf("%" STR(FORMAT_SIZE) "s", ...);` where `STR` is a/the (famous?) stringification macro.

Comment: It avoids magic numbers appearing in (all over?) the code or if array and format string are located far away from one another, so *can* be useful sometimes, on the other hand, it's pretty ugly as well – and doesn't cover dynamically allocated arrays either (one would have to print the length into the format string then – errmm...).

Answer (score 0):

First of all you aren’t traversing your list during insertion. Then you can shorten your code this way.

```
struct Word **trav = node; // double pointer holds address        of root

while(*trav != null){
    if( id < *trav->id){
        trav = *trav->left;
    }else{
        trav = *trav->right;
    }
 }

 new_data = new Word(…);
 *trav = &new_data;
```

(Sorry im on my phone so hard to code)